# pandas dataframe groupby sum index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, I want to

```
    FROM:  
             dow    yield
           0    F   2
           1    F   3
           2    M   4
           3    M   6
           4    TH  7
    TO:

          dow    ysum
      0     F   5
      1     M   10
      2     TH  7
```

butI got this :

```
               |yield
         -------------
          dow  |
         -------------
           F   |5
           M   |10
           TH  |7
```

This is how I did it:

```
    d1=['F','F','M','M','TH']
    d2=[2,3,4,6,7]
    d = {'dow': d1, 'yield': d2}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=None)
    df1= df.groupby('dow').sum()
```

How could get result use dow as a column in stead of index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First column is `index`, so you can add parameter `as_index=False`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('dow', as_index=False).sum()
print (df1)
  dow  yield
0   F      5
1   M     10
2  TH      7
```

Or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('dow').sum().reset_index()
print (df1)
  dow  yield
0   F      5
1   M     10
2  TH      7
```